# cleveref label ending with parenthesis not recognized

Tags: cross-referencing, texstudio, cleveref

I'm not sure if this is intended but when I have a \cref label which ends with a closing parenthesis, the label is not recognized. For example:

```
\label{f:Data(SR2_M0.8)}
```

is not recognized. However, if a character is added so that the closing bracket is not the last character, for example:

```
\label{f:Dittmar(SR2_M0.8)a}
```

it is recognized.

Any ideas how to work around this issue? Also, is there a way to include a comma within a \cref label? For example:

```
\label{f:Dittmar(SR2,M0.8)}
```

EDIT:
I realized that the reference shows up correctly in the produced document (which is what really matters), however, it is not recognized within the editor (TexStudio), ie. it is underlined and gives a 'label missing' warning. Interestingly this is not the case for a regular \ref label.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}      

 \usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{x}
In \cref{e:equ(test)}

\begin{equation}
\label{e:equ(test)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I have no problem with labels including parentheses. Could you post a full compilable, yet minimal,  example reproducing the problem?

Comment: The label name with `(...)` either with or without additional characters works, but the `cleveref` documentation clearly says, that `,` aren't possible anly longer in a label name, since `\cref{a,b}` is interpreted as referring to **two** labels `a` and `b`, not to `a,b`. Replace `,` with `;` and it works

Comment: I can confirm the problem described in your edit. I'm not really sure why that is, though. Have you tried raising this up to the TeXstudio team at Sourceforge?

Comment: Your MWE compiles properly for me. What version of `cleveref` are you using? I have `cleveref 2018/02/08 v0.21.1`.

Comment: The MWE works for me without warning as well. From your question the only issue you have is with your editor's label/syntax highlighting. This is something that should be raised with the developers and should be reported as a bug or feature request. I'm therefore voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is at best a bug report for the TeXstudio developers.